# Android Kotlin How to get all items from an array

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

How to I get all items from an array instead of just 1

```
 Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${productfeed.variants[0].option_values[0].name}")
```

Lets say I had 30 "variants" and I wanted to get all all of the `option_values[0].name` from them how would I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: The array *is* all the items. To get a String containing all the items in an array, use `joinToString()`. This is only necessary for Arrays. Lists can be used directly because they have a sensible `toString()` function.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
productfeed.variants.forEach { variant ->
    Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${variant.option_values[0].name}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked better than anything that I have tried!

Comment: @LawrenceValdivia No problem!